# How to find a general expression to include all angles which have the same sine?

Tags: trigonometry

In S L Loney's Trigonometry book on page 78, article 82, the author combines 2r$\pi$+$\alpha$ and (2r+1)$\pi$-$\alpha$ and arrives at this equation n$\pi$+(-1)<sup>n</sup>$\alpha$, which is a general expression to include all angles which have the same sine.

Then plug in n=2r and n=2r+1 in to the last equation and gets the first two respectively.

I understand n=2r is an even number of revolutions and n=2r+1 is an odd number of revolutions around the circle.

What does even and odd number of revolutions have to do with this ?
What does 'n' stand for in the last equation ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how the author arrived at:
$n\pi+(-1)^n\alpha$
from

$(2r+1)\pi-\alpha$
and
$2r\pi+\alpha$

note that $(-1)^{2r+1} = -1$ and $(-1)^{2r} = 1$ when r is an integer